# Why is this projection in a draftsman document incomplete?

Tags: altium

I am working on generating a draftsman document. 3 components have a line going through them, as shown below, as if the footprint outline is incomplete.

The draftsman document is using the BodyProjectionSimple as the geometry source for the components, and the line is still there when I use BodyProjection. Below I have included the 3d View of the same component, as well as a picture of the layer stack.

The footprint was generated using Altium's built in IPC Compliant Footprint Wizard.

[image: Draftsman Document Simple Body Projection]
[image: 3d view of the component in question]
[image: 2d layer stack of the component in question]

Any clue what might be causing this to happen? or how I can go about fixing it?

Comment: there is more wrong than just a diagonal line ... it is possible that the geometry description is in a text file, perhaps xml formatted, and the file is corrupted ... it could be that the designer did not complete the work on the component definition

Comment: I suggest you post to https://bugcrunch.live.altium.com/#Bugs/New